# Using std::span with buffers - C++

Tags: c++, buffer

I am exploring a possibly safer and more convenient way to handle buffers, either with

1. fixed size known at compile time
2. size known at runtime

What is the advice of using *static extent* vs *dynamic extent*? The answer may seem obvious but I got confused when testing with examples below. It looks like I can manipulate extent by my own choice by choosing how I initialize the span. Any thoughts about the code examples? What are the correct ways to initialize the span in the examples?

Note that even if the examples use strings the normal use should be `uint8_t` or `std::byte`. The Windows and MS compiler specifics are not crucial.

edit:
Updated code

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC_NEW
// ... includes
#include <cstdlib>
#include <crtdbg.h>

enum appconsts : uint8_t { buffersize = 0xFF };

HRESULT __stdcall FormatBuffer(std::span<wchar_t/*, appconsts::buffersize*/> buffer) noexcept
{
    _RPTFN(_CRT_WARN, "FormatBuffer with size of buffer=%d, threadid=0x%8.8X\n", buffer.size(), ::GetCurrentThreadId());
    errno_t er = swprintf_s(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), L"test of buffers with std::span, buffer size: %zu", buffer.size());

    return er > 0 ? S_OK : E_INVALIDARG; 
}

extern "C" int32_t __cdecl
wmain([[maybe_unused]] _In_ int32_t argc,[[maybe_unused]] _In_reads_(argc) _Pre_z_ wchar_t* argv[]) 
{
    _RPTFN(_CRT_WARN, "Executing main thread, argc=%d, threadid=0x%8.8X\n", argc, ::GetCurrentThreadId());
    int32_t ir = 0;

    wchar_t buffer1[appconsts::buffersize];
    ir = FormatBuffer(buffer1);

    wchar_t* buffer2 = new wchar_t[appconsts::buffersize];
    ir = FormatBuffer(std::span<wchar_t/*, appconsts::buffersize*/>(buffer2, appconsts::buffersize));
    delete[] buffer2;

    std::unique_ptr<wchar_t[]> buffer3 = std::make_unique<wchar_t[]>(appconsts::buffersize);
    ir = FormatBuffer(std::span<wchar_t/*, appconsts::buffersize*/>(buffer3.get(), appconsts::buffersize));

    std::vector<wchar_t> buffer4(appconsts::buffersize);
    ir = FormatBuffer(std::span<wchar_t/*, appconsts::buffersize*/>(buffer4/*, appconsts::buffersize*/));

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return ir;
}
```

---

**New code**
Things get a bit clearer with a new version of the example. To get static extent, the size needs to be set in `FormatBuffer` and only the fixed `buffer1` will fit. The [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) text is a bit confusing. The following is giving dynamic extent.

```
enum appconsts : uint8_t { buffersize = 0xFF };

HRESULT __stdcall FormatBuffer(std::span<wchar_t/*, appconsts::buffersize*/> buffer) noexcept
{
    _RPTFN(_CRT_WARN, "FormatBuffer with size of buffer=%d, span extent=%d, threadid=0x%8.8X\n", 
        buffer.size(), buffer.extent == std::dynamic_extent ? -1 : buffer.extent, ::GetCurrentThreadId());

    errno_t er = swprintf_s(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), L"test of buffers with std::span, buffer size: %zu", buffer.size());

    return er > 0 ? S_OK : E_INVALIDARG; 
}

HRESULT __stdcall CreateBuffer(size_t runtimesize) noexcept
{
    _RPTFN(_CRT_WARN, "CreateBuffer with runtime size of buffer=%d, threadid=0x%8.8X\n", runtimesize, ::GetCurrentThreadId());
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    wchar_t buffer1[appconsts::buffersize]{};
    hr = FormatBuffer(buffer1);

    std::unique_ptr<wchar_t[]> buffer3 = std::make_unique<wchar_t[]>(runtimesize /*appconsts::buffersize*/);
    hr = FormatBuffer(std::span<wchar_t/*, runtimesize*/>(buffer3.get(), runtimesize));

    std::vector<wchar_t> buffer4(appconsts::buffersize);
    hr = FormatBuffer(std::span<wchar_t/*, appconsts::buffersize*/>(buffer4/*, appconsts::buffersize*/));

    return hr; 
}

extern "C" int32_t __cdecl 
wmain([[maybe_unused]] _In_ int32_t argc,[[maybe_unused]] _In_reads_(argc) _Pre_z_ wchar_t* argv[]) 
{
    _RPTFN(_CRT_WARN, "Executing main thread, argc=%d, threadid=0x%8.8X\n", argc, ::GetCurrentThreadId());

    //(void)argc;(void)argv;
    int32_t ir = 0;

    ir = CreateBuffer(static_cast<size_t>(argc) * appconsts::buffersize);

    return ir;
}
```

Comment: `new wchar_t(appconsts::buffersize)`? Are you use you should be using parentheses `()` instead of square brackets `[]` here? I'm voting to close as a typo.

Comment: And if your update was to fix an unrelated error, then that suggest your original question was too unfocused. Since you now have an answer which very likely solved *one* of the problems mentioned in the original question, I would rather suggest you delete this question and post a new question that focus more on the actual problem you have and want help with.

Comment: @Some programmer dude, no the question is about std::span and the use of its extent

Comment: OK, I'm unsure what to do now as the site clearly advise NOT to delete the question and the answer isn't on topic, so I guess I leave it as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(the part on runtime error was removed from the question)*

In a nutshell: use dynamic extent, and initialize in the simplest way, like:

```cpp
wchar_t buffer1[appconsts::buffersize];
ir = FormatBuffer(buffer1);

wchar_t* buffer2 = new wchar_t[appconsts::buffersize];
ir = FormatBuffer({buffer2, appconsts::buffersize}); // won’t compile without the size
delete[] buffer2;

std::unique_ptr<wchar_t[]> buffer3 = std::make_unique<wchar_t[]>(appconsts::buffersize);
ir = FormatBuffer({buffer3.get(), appconsts::buffersize}); // won’t compile without the size

std::vector<wchar_t> buffer4(appconsts::buffersize);
ir = FormatBuffer(buffer4);
```

Out of these examples, only the first will work if the function expects a fixed-extent span (and only if that extent is exactly the same as array length). Which is good as according to the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/span), constructing a fixed-extent `std::span` with wrong size is an outright UB. Ouch.

Fixed-extent span is only useful if its size is a part of the API contract. Like, if your function *needs* 42 coefficients no matter what, `std::span<double, 42>` is the right way. But if your function may sensibly work with any buffer size, there is no point in hard-coding the particular size used today.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```cpp
wchar_t* buffer2 = new wchar_t(appconsts::buffersize);
ir = FormatBuffer(std::span<wchar_t/*, appconsts::buffersize*/>(buffer2, appconsts::buffersize));
delete buffer2; // Critical error detected c0000374
```

`new wchar_t(appconsts::buffersize)` doesn’t create a buffer of that size. It allocates a *single* `wchar_t` and initializes it with `appconsts::buffersize` as a value. To allocate an array, use `new wchar_t[appconsts::buffersize]`. And to free it, use `delete[] buffer2`.

Comment: Of course, thanks! But your answer doesn't address the question or give any advice on the use of span.